# Protractor assert that an element is not visible

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

On our site there is an icon that hides/unhides the menu. I created the following script to test it :

```
 it('Hamburger Menu Click Validation', function () {
    expect(Hamburger_Menu.isDisplayed());
    Hamburger_Menu.click();
    browser.sleep(1000);
    expect(foo.isDisplayed()).toBe(false);
    Hamburger_Menu.click();
    browser.sleep(1000);
    expect (foo.isDisplayed().toBe(true));
    // expect (invisibilityOf())
})
```

The statement "expect(foo.isDisplayed()).toBe(false);" is copied from this [website](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isDisplayed). I do not see any reason for its failure, but when I run the test I get the following error, which says that :foo.isDisplayed(...).toBe is not a function!! . How can I validate if the menu gets hidden using expect function?

> estBed Tests Hamburger Menu Click Validation Message: Failed: foo.isDisplayed(...).toBe is not a function Stack: TypeError: foo.isDisplayed(...).toBe is not a function at UserContext. (C:\FCPS_I\FCPS\FCPS\TestBed.js:16:35) at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:112:25 at new ManagedPromise (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1077:7) at ControlFlow.promise (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2505:12) at schedulerExecute (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:95:18) at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14) at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27) at asyncRun (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27) at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) From: Task: Run it("Hamburger Menu Click Validation") in control flow at UserContext. (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:94:19) From asynchronous test: Error at Suite. (C:\FCPS_I\FCPS\FCPS\TestBed.js:9:5) at Object. (C:\FCPS_I\FCPS\FCPS\TestBed.js:1:63) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32) at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just closing the parenthesis incorrectly:

```
expect(foo.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
expect(foo.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

providing foo of ElementFinder type